# I want to use useSafeAreaInsets in the expo to get the paddingbottom, but I get an error

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

```
import { SafeAreaProvider, useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
export default function App() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
          <WebView ... />
       </View>
   </SafeAreaProvider>
);
```

An error occurs.
I wrote the code at the top and it does.
I updated to the latest version of expo and it doesn't work.
I want to get the bottom padding value of the iPhone.
Is there any way to do this?

'''Error: No safe area value available. Make sure you are rendering '''`<SafeAreaProvider>` at the top of your app.

I found the link by accident and it seems to have stopped 2 years ago, so if there is another way, please help.
https://github.com/a-eid/expo-static-safearea-insets

I want to get the bottom padding value of the iPhone.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call useSafeAreaInsets in a child component, not in the same component as the Provider.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Main />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  )
}

//export default function App() {
function Main() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  return (
    <Root>
      <View>
      ...
      </Vide>
    </Root>
  )
}
```

I did what @johnhaup said and it worked.
However, I wish there was an easier way to do it..